# NAS no longer mounting but FSTAB not changed

Tags: linux, mount, linux-mint, nas, fstab

My Linux box is set up to automatically mount a NAS volume on startup. I did this by including the following line in the FSTAB file.

```
//192.168.1.106/Media/ /media/media cifs users,rw,username=****,password=****,iocharset=utf8,uid=****,gid=****,acl,sec=ntlm,vers=2.0 0 0
```

The NAS username, uid and gid are the same. This user account is only used with the Linux box.

But when I started my Linux box after coming home from a Christmas break, the volume stopped mounting.

The /media/media mount point is still present in the file structure.

When I double-click on the Media volume's icon, I received a "mount error(2): Operation not supported" message.

The only recent major change to the Linux box was a kernel update. The NAS has had a firmware upgrade, but its settings and IP address did not change.

The error message referred to the dmesg log for additional info. I don't understand what the log says. It can be downloaded using this [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3abo9wfmvhfyckx/dmesg.txt?dl=0).

The volume will mount if I enter the following in Terminal, using an admin account:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=****,password=**** //192.168.1.106/Media /media/media
```

All the advice I've found says to put the line I entered above in FSTAB. I've found nothing about a NAS not mounting when it did before, and settings haven't changed.

The Linux box runs Emby's media server, and the media library is stored on the NAS.

The Linux box is running Linux Mint 20.3.

Comment: I tried changing “cifs” to “auto” and “ver” to 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0; putting the shared volume’s name (“Media”) in title and lower case; using Timeshift to restore my system to before the kernel update; and re-install cifs-utils. None of that fixed the issue. I’ve had problems storing the username and password in a file (not Linux related; with me), which is why they’re in the fstab.

Comment: Your fstab entry has a lot of options missing in the command line version (iocharset=utf8 and acl,sec=ntlm,vers=2.0) - what happens if you remove those from the fstab entry?

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for the suggestion. I tried removing the "extras", and the volume mounted properly when "sec=ntlm" was taken out.

Answer (score 1):

Removing "sec=ntml" from the FSTAB line enabled the volume to mount. (Thanks [davidgo](https://superuser.com/users/137786/davidgo) for the suggestion.)

Comment: If you read this, please click the tick if you're able and it's not been ticked yet. I can't mark this answer as the solution for a couple of days, and I'm bound to forget to do it by then.

Comment: Hi Richard, You are the only person that can mark the answer as accepted - I think there is a 1 day stand-down period before you can accept your own answer.   (I've enough reputation that it does not bother me in the slightest, but for future reference its best practice to invite a person with a comment that turned out to be the solution to write it up as an answer and to then accept it)